# SQL CASE WHEN and @x variable usage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have select where I need to identify groups of values in range. But select works unreliable. I have a problem with its inner part where I using `CASE WHEN` ... the goal is mark each continuous series of values with a unique grouping value. I expect this:
WHEN value of column is in range then not change the group number
ELSE increment group number by one

I don't know what is wrong. Thank all of you for your advices.

```
SELECT *
, CASE WHEN value >= 17 AND value <= 18 THEN @x=@x ELSE @x=@x+1 END grp 
FROM my_table
```

I expect:

```
value     grp
18.9607   0
17.8623   1
17.0396   1
19.8252   2
19.746    3
```

But I get:

```
value     grp
18.9607   null
17.8623   null
17.0396   null
19.8252   null
19.746    null
```

in fact all grp values is null

Comment: I find solution of this problem. I miss @x variable initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to enumerate the values where the "breaks" are values between 17 and 18, I would suggest:

```
select t.*,
       (@grp := if(value >= 17 and value <= 18, @grp,
                   @grp + 1
                  )
       ) as grp
from my_table t cross join
     (select @grp := 0) params;
```

You can initialize the value directly in your query.